# loading a java class at runtime through java

Tags: java, reflection, classloader

I have a jar file which is separate folder named lib so i am trying to load a jar from there as show in the below code but i am getting exception that is malformed exception please advise how can i correct this please advise

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;

public class JarFileLoader extends URLClassLoader {
  public JarFileLoader(URL[] urls) {
    super(urls);
  }

  public void addFile(String path) throws MalformedURLException {
    String urlPath = "jar:file://" + path + "!/";
    addURL(new URL(urlPath));
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      System.out.println("First attempt...");
      Class.forName("org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HssfSheet");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Failed.");
    }
    try {
      URL urls[] = {};
      JarFileLoader cl = new JarFileLoader(urls);
      cl.addFile("/lib/poi3.10final.jar");
      System.out.println("Second attempt...");
      cl.loadClass("org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HssfSheet");
      System.out.println("Success!");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.out.println("Failed.");
      ex.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you copy/paste the exception and show where it is thrown in the code?

Comment: It is not able to load class from /lib location

Comment: It is getting failed in both first and second attempt,  I believe issue is at the location string of poi jar that I am giving

Comment: I tried with a jar which is present on my machine (took a random jar in ~/.m2/repository) and did the appropriate replacement in your code. First attempt failed (as expected) and second attempt succeeded. I suspect that the path of your jar is wrong.

Comment: My guess is that the path you give is interpreted as an absolute path. Can you try `cl.addFile("lib/poi3.10final.jar");` or `cl.addFile("poi3.10final.jar");` or `cl.addFile("/absolute/path/to/poi3.10final.jar");`?

Comment: That's great Thanks request you to please post the code that you have tried on your machine please so that I can grasp more Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

*This should be a comment but I do not have enough place.* Please don't vote.

I took a random jar which is present on my machine :

> /home/adenoyelle/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.2/antlr-2.7.2.jar

This jar contains a lot a classes. One of them is `antlr.ActionElement`. So here is what I changed in your code :

```
try {
  System.out.println("First attempt...");
  Class.forName("antlr.ActionElement"); //Changed this line
} catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println("Failed.");
}
try {
  URL urls[] = {};
  JarFileLoader cl = new JarFileLoader(urls);

  //Changed this line
  cl.addFile("/home/adenoyelle/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.2/antlr-2.7.2.jar");
  System.out.println("Second attempt...");
  cl.loadClass("antlr.ActionElement"); //Changed this line
  System.out.println("Success!");
} catch (Exception ex) {
  System.out.println("Failed.");
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output :

```
First attempt...
Failed.
Second attempt...
Success!
```

My guess is that the path to your jar is wrong. I did it the easy way by providing an absolute path (and the path that you give is also interpreted as an absolute path which is probably the root of your problem).

Please try the following :

- cl.addFile("lib/poi3.10final.jar");
- cl.addFile("poi3.10final.jar");
- cl.addFile("C:/absolute/path/to/poi3.10final.jar");

Comment: Thanks but I am using window machine so shall I give the path that include C drive also under Linux as u shown it will work fine

Comment: @sss no problem. On Windows, the absolute path will just look like `C:/path/to/your/jar` (edited).

Comment: Thanks I was trying C:\\path\\poi. Jar,  so I think it's backward slash issue as  I can see in your window path issue you have use forward slash

Comment: @sss paths should not be sensitive to forward/backward slashs, even on windows. I use forward slashs so that I don't need to escape them.